# Existence of this following limit

Tags: limits

This is an exercise.

Does the following limit exist?

$$\lim_{x\to 0,y\to 0} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}$$

I don't know how to deal with it.

Thanks ahead:)

Comment: The form of the fraction suggests you look at paths to $(0,0)$ of two different kinds, one where $x = y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $(x,y)=(t,0)$ with $t \to 0$, and get a trivial zero limit. If $(x,y)=(t,t)$, then you get
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^4}{t^4}=1.
$$
Hence the limit does not exist.